# When running npm start how do I access other html pages in a different folder from index?

Tags: html, npm, file-structure

I currently have an index.html which doesn't have much in it and want to access the app.html which is in a subfolder from index.html as shown here.
[image: file setup]

My other html file is in app. In addition how do I reference that page in say a button on my index file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app.html is located here: app/app.html

Try linking to it like so:

```
<a href="app/app.html">App</a>
```